# Админ панель без CSS стилей

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Есть непонятная проблема с админ панелью WordPress. Загрузил сайт заказчику на хостинг, сам сайт работает корректно, CSS и JS, всё подгружает, но админ панель отображает без CSS .. Хотя на моём тестовом хостинге всё нормально работает.

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема??

Comment: Если тестовый хостинг под виндой, то надо проверить употребление строчных и прописных букв в пути и имени файла css.

Comment: Как переносили сайт?

Comment: Переносил ZIP архивом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561